# fetch Linkedin post update feed with jquery

Tags: jquery-plugins, linkedin-api

I want to fetch linkedin group or company post updates via ajax to be displayed on a webpage. To be specific I'm looking for something like this plugin [named jtwitter](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.it/2009/11/jquery-twitter-plugin-update-jtwitter.html) which fetches twitter posts. Now I just want a simple updates feed so I was wondering if there is any jquery plugin that allows to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was searching for similar solution.

Here's a jQuery Socialist plugin which can grab latest posts and updates from popular social networks:
https://github.com/iatek/jquery-socialist

I didn't try it yet but it seems that it fit your needs.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: hey, thanks for the plugin. I've found it out a few monts ago and it's quite handy. I'm selecting your answer as accepted. :)